# Treat unicode character plus diacritic as a single character?

Tags: vb.net, string, unicode, encoding

In my VB.NET application I compare words that are recorded using IPA, many of which have many diacritic marks.  In one of the comparisons, I compare the words character by character.  But when I iterate over the characters, the diacritic marks come out as separate characters (as I would expect since this is unicode):

```
o`ku`ku`
```

However, a u character is different than a u plus an accent for the purposes of this program and needs to be distinguished.

Is there a good way to iterate over unicode strings in such a way that characters and their accents are considered one character?  I'm trying to avoid having to hardcode all the combinations that combine to be considered a single character.

Edit:

The Normalize() method does work for characters with simple diacritic marks that have a single-character unicode representation, such as most accented vowels.  However, this does not work for more obscure symbols, like `uˤ` and `uˠ`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what string.Normalize() takes care of.  You can use the Normalize(NormalizationForm) override to control this explicitly.

Comment: This works for simple accent marks, but some of the more complicated IPA characters are not combined (because there is no single-character representation for them).  For example, the ˤ modifier does not get combined.  I will update my question to reflect this.

Comment: How could that be a problem?  The words you're trying to compare won't have the combining glyph either.

Comment: The problem is that the combining glyphs are important information for the purposes of this program, and not having them changes the calculations.  ɔ̃  is a completely different character than ɔ.